# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException in PDI

Tags: mysql, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have problem with MySQL in PDI (Kettle). This error appears in process of reading information by Input Table. Even if all data is gived out of base successfully, this error appears and, probably, doesn't affect on transformation.

```
Error comitting connection 
Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown. 

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown. 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)...
```

Why this problem happens?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same MySQL database connection throughout? You really need to include your source code in the question, it will be hard for the community to help you without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a MySQL error documented in a manual page with a nice title: [My sql server has gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html).

Matt Casters (the main author of Kettle) gives a bunch of solutions on the [Pentaho wiki](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MySQL) which is not yet uploaded on <s>Hitachi</s> Vantara forum.

Matt's first solution is to increase the `net_write_timeout`. The default is 60 and he did increase it to 1800, mentioning that less may be sufficient.

In order to do this, edit the connection and select `Options` on the left panel. 
Then write net_write_timeout in he `Parameters` column and 1800 as `value`.